# can you clarify the policy on using Google Drive logos on my app?

Tags: google-drive-api

The documentation is confusing in regards to using the logos as buttons. Specifically I'm seeing these two conflicting comments under ***Use the Drive Badge and Brand***:

> **In your application**
>
> As a button that initiates an action with Google Drive, such as saving to Google Drive
>
> **Things not to do**
>
> Do not use the Google or Google Drive logos on the button

Answer (score 0):

For buttons, it is OK to use either plain text like "Save to Google Drive" *or* the icon with a tooltip.  Both of these uses are shown [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/branding#in_your_application).

The thing *not* to do is use the ['text logo'](https://developers.google.com/drive/branding#using_the_google_drive_brand) image inside the button. For example, don't do this:
[image]